# R.Java keeps disappearing

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

This question might have been posted before. However, I have checked all the links and have tried all of it. First of all, I am following the tutorial on developer.android like everyone else with this problem. I've reached the part where I need to add items to my action bar. For this, I was asked to create a file within my res/menu folder called main_activity_actions.xml. Inside this file is the following

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I was told to also add the icon attribute with the search icon but since I didn't have the png image, and adding it to my drawable folder (which I read how to do in another post here) was causing this R.java problem again, I deleted it and removed that attribute all together.
I have added the corresponding strings to match the above to my res/values/strings.xml also
I'm pretty sure that nothing is wrong in my xml files. I have tried building, cleaning in all possible combinations. I have tried fixing project properties. I have checked whether the android.R has been imported in any of my .java files. My build targets also haven't caused any problems before. All my SDK tools are updated.

Also, I keep getting the

```
parseSdkContent failed
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Error every now and then. For this too, I have tried deleting the .android folder in my home directory and then restarting eclipse. That solves the problem temporarily. But before I know it, it's back.

I'm running on Eclipse (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is something which I haven't tried yet and which you feel I need to, please do link me to it. I apologize in advance for not finding it and having to repost this. The errors come in the java files of my /src folder.

Thanks!

Comment: in my experience, the R.java problem was happened mostly bcz of the xml file, if its name contains a space/special character, and the another thing I hve got was with the xml I kept inside raw folder. also check the name of image that you added!

Comment: @bachu the name of the xml file I created in my res/menu was main_activity_actions.xml. I don't think there is anything wrong with that name though. Also, I didn't add any image. Whatever I added before I removed.

Comment: anything in console..?

Comment: @bachu Nope, it's blank.

Comment: Update the eclipse plugin and sdk. Donno why but when a new update is out the r.java starts the come and go...